# why V4 compatibility API is still needed in 2015

Tags: android, android-fragments

API Level is currently at version **22** (or more), V4 was around 2010.

So:

- Why is this compatibility layer still needed and required in many classes?
- Is there a better way for us and Google to manage API evolution?
- Is there a target defined to remove v4 compatibility layers (and others), or is it expected to be there 'forever'?

Comment: Do you want your app(s) to be **compatible with** the (still listed in the DashBoards) API Level 8 (or 10 or **anything lower than the latest API Kevel**)? Then, you **really need** the support library. `Is there a target defined to remove v4 compatibility` Your `minSDKVersion` in the Manifest file. And/or Gradle fiddlings, for AS users...

Comment: I target API level 16. But most helpers in Android Studio (like create a new fragment) still use it. Seems unecessary complex to support a very small subset of handset.

Comment: **No**. There's some confusion, here. **Target** API Level is different from **Minimum** API Level. `minSdkVersion` tells the IDE which API Level you want you app to be **compatible** with, while `targetSdkVersion` tells the IDE API Level to compile it with, which declares which function set you want to use.

Comment: sorry, I've mixed the minimum and the target. I was of course talking of minimumSdkVersion. But the question is more general: this kind of compatibility layer should be used in very specific cases , but seems to be the norm.Is there a target date or a roadmap to remove them?

Comment: v4 compat is never going away because v4 compat has specific items only available in it such as the popular `viewpager`

Comment: You use the support library **ONLY** if you are to use functions of the new API Level which wheren't present in the minimumSdkVersion.

Comment: of course not, because it was not the question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this compatibility layer still needed and required in many classes?

for backwards compatibility of older android versions and bug fixes are more frequent in the support library since all they have to do is put out an update to the repository vs putting out an update to the OS

> Is there a better way for us and Google to manage API evolution?

Not really because it takes forever for manufacturers and carriers to update to the latest OS

> Is there a target defined to remove v4 compatibility layers (and others), or is it expected to be there 'forever'?

its probably never going to get removed because it has items specific to that library only and provides the greatest backwards compatibility of any support library